# Count coincidences between rows in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to write a query in SQL Server 2014 that counts the number of coincidences (but just when those coincidences are more than 1) between the rows in two tables, into a new column. The structure is like this:

> table_a:
>    ================
>   c1 | c2 | c3 | c4
>
> 11  | 30 | 70 | 90
>   20 | 80 | 95 | 99
>   15 | 39 | 40 | 41
>   ...
>
> table_b:
>    ================
>   n1 | n2 | n3 | n4
>
> 30  | 65 | 90 | 95
>   20 | 80 | 90 | 99
>   15 | 80 | 95 | 99
>   ...

And I want to add a column in a query after the columns in `table_a` like this:

> query:
>    ================
>   c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5
>
> 11  | 30 | 70 | 90  | 2
>   20 | 80 | 95 | 99  | 6
>   15 | 39 | 40 | 41  | 0
>   ...

In other words, for each row in `table_a` check how many numbers match each row in `table_b` , afterwards sum all results greater than 1 and paste next to the row in `table_a`.

I have the following code but I get wrong output:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.table_a.c1, dbo.table_a.c2,  
    dbo.table_a.c3, dbo.table_a.c4, dbo.table_a.c5, dbo.table_a.c6,  
    COUNT('c1 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c2 = n1 or n2 or n3 or n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c3 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c4 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c5 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c6 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6') AS c5  
FROM  dbo.table_a CROSS JOIN dbo.[table_b]  
GROUP BY dbo.table_a.c1, dbo.table_a.c2, dbo.table_a.c3, dbo.table_a.c4,  
  dbo.table_a.c5, dbo.table_a.c6  
HAVING   (COUNT('c1 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c2 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c3 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c4 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')  
    + COUNT('c5 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6')   
    + COUNT('c6 = n1 or n2 or n3 or  n4 or  n5 or  n6') > 1)
ORDER BY c5 DESC
```

Any help would be appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 2):

```
;with cte(n) as(
    select n1 from table_b union all
    select n2 from table_b union all
    select n3 from table_b union all
    select n4 from table_b
)
,counted(n, c) as(
    select n, c = count(n) from cte group by n
)
select
    a.*, b.cc
from table_a a
cross apply(
    select cc = sum(case when c > 1 then c else 0 end)
    from counted
    where
        n = a.c1
        or n = a.c2
        or n = a.c3
        or n = a.c4
)b
```

Comment: Answer is almost great, but in the last step i'm getting the total sum instead of the sum of thoose over 1